# Proof of an equation in a Poisson Process

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

In a Poisson Process with parameter $\lambda$, if $X_n$ is the time of the rth arrival.

> Prove:
>
> $$\sum^\infty_{n=1}fx_n(x)=\lambda\quad\text{for all}\ x\gt0$$

I’m new to Statistics and the Poisson Process in general. I know that $N(0) = 0$, that the number of arrivals in any interval $a\gt0$ has a Poisson$(\lambda a)$ distribution and that $N(t)$ increments are independent but I don’t see how any of that helps me to prove/show the given equation. I would appreciate any and all help.

[image]

Comment: Can you describe what  $f_{X_n}(x)$ represents?

Comment: From my notes it seems to represent the Erlang Distribution. 
https://postimg.cc/94Mg3TwJ
I have posted the formula given to us, it uses different symbols but I'm pretty certain of it.

Comment: Then I suggest you add those up.  Remember that $\exp(z)=1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots$

Comment: I don't quite understand, wouldn't Poisson exponential cover the "Interarrival Time Distr." rather then time to kth arrival?

From the Erlang Distribution equation, Yk=Xn, y=x, and k=r. There is no change to t or .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum\limits^\infty_{n=1}f_{X_n}(x) \\= \sum\limits^\infty_{n=1} \dfrac{\lambda^{n-1} t^{n-1}e^{-\lambda t}}{(n-1)!}\lambda \\=  e^{-\lambda t}\lambda\sum\limits^\infty_{n=1} \dfrac{(\lambda t)^{n-1} }{(n-1)!} \\=  e^{-\lambda t}\lambda\sum\limits^\infty_{m=0} \dfrac{(\lambda t)^{m} }{m!} \\= e^{-\lambda t}\lambda e^{\lambda t} \\ = \lambda.$$